# can't able to run demos of dojo

Tags: dojo

Sorry if it's not the right place to ask this question as I am not sure that where to ask this question.

My problem is that I have downloaded the demos of dojo (from http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.5/) and now as I open any one (demo.html) of them in my browser (in localhsot//)

I'm only able to see blank page with some text of demo(such as instructions or like that) but not the DEMO! I have read the README files included with the demo folder (for confirming any change in file source or path) but proved not helpful. I also tried with changing the included script path of dojo but failed.

As I am a beginner  I don't know what's the problem..help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demos download only contains demos. The next step is to download the dojo toolkit. You can get [Dojo 1.85 release](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.5/dojo-release-1.8.5-src.zip) at the same URL you provided above.

Download the toolkit, unzip it, and drag the dijit, dojo, dojox and util directories into the same directory as your demos folder. This should get you going.

The directory structure will resemble:

```
/dojo-release-1.8.5
--- demos/
--- dijit/
--- dojo/
--- dojox/
--- util/
```

Comment: oh i am so sorry i didn't mentioned, it works for me thanks again :)